Handling the fifth in counterpoint inverted at the octave
In counterpoint textbooks inversion of two parts is often explained with a chart like this...

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

...with noting...

perfect and imperfect intervals remain so after inversion
dissonances invert to dissonances
consonances invert to consonances, except...
consonant fifth invert to dissonant fourths

I check my three counterpoint textbooks - Piston, Kennan, and Jeppesen - and all of them advise treating the fifth in the original as a "dissonant" when writing invertible counterpoint at the octave and essential recommend avoiding the fifth altogether.
However, in the past, I thought I read that the consonant fifth inverted to a dissonant fourth could be "fixed" by treating the resulting fourth with a suspension. My three textbooks don't say that, and I want some examples of how I might do it. I came up with these...

So, the "fix" of the fifth inverted to fourth is the resolving step down to a third. But I realized that in order to make that as a properly prepared suspension I needed to consider the approach to the fifth in the original counterpoint. I can only thing of three consonant approaches to a fifth, and each of them upon inversion creates a different kind of non-chord tone motion.
I tried to make the harmony roughly functional, so I'm aiming more for 18th century counterpoint rather than 16th century.
Are these good examples?
Is there a better way to do this? Better exemplars?
Also, if metrical placement could be better, I'm especially interested in that.
